# Recursively compare root directory on Linux system A to root directory on Linux system B

Tags: centos, rsync, diff

I'm trying to diff all files on two Linux systems using rsync and ssh, by using the --dry-run option so it doesn't synchronize any files/folders.  What am I doing wrong?  I'm currently in the root directory when running this command.

Command:

```
rsync --dry-run -v 'ssh -p 22' root@192.168.86.128:/
```

Output:

```
[root@localhost /]# rsync --dry-run -v 'ssh -p 22' root@192.168.86.128:/
The authenticity of host '192.168.86.128 (192.168.86.128)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 22:e5:15:2e:0b:69:5d:cd:63:84:83:61:b7:ce:19:56.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '192.168.86.128' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
root@192.168.86.128's password:
rsync: link_stat "/ssh -p 22" failed: No such file or directory (2)

sent 16 bytes  received 12 bytes  1.70 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00 (DRY RUN)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1039) [sender=3.0.6]
[root@localhost /]#
```

Comment: Either you forgot the ```-e``` option before the ```ssh -p 22``` part or just skip it, because ```ssh -p 22``` should be the default anyway. But you forgot the ```[DEST]``` part for [rsync](https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/rsync.html)

Answer (score 0):

This worked when comparing system A to system B.

```
rsync --dry-run -r root@192.168.86.129:/ /
```

This worked when comparing system B to system A:

```
rsync --dry-run -r root@192.168.86.128:/ /
```

Answer (score 0):

[Meld](http://meldmerge.org/) compares folders recursively with a friendly interface.